# OnDisconnect event on idHttpServer

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, indy, indy10

Is there any event that is fired when the `idHttpServer` disconnects?

By disconnect I dont mean when a client disconnects, but when the `idHTTPServer` disconnect for some reason.

I can explain it better: when `idHTTPServer`is listening to a socket port and, for some unknown reason, the computer disconnects from the network (lets say, for example, that the the network becomes unavailable) the component does not work anymore (it stops listening to the port) and, in that case, I need to reconnect (reopen the port). The `idHttpServer.OnDisconnect`, according to the help, is only fired when a client disconnects from the server.

Comment: I would say the [`OnListenException`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/TIdCustomTCPServer_OnListenException.html) is what you need, but it's just a guess.

Comment: @TLama: i dont think so. According to the help: OnListenException is signalled with the server context in the listener thread when an exception other than EAbort occurs during execution of the specific listener thread.

Comment: `EAbort` is used internally if the listening socket is closed while waiting for a new client connection, or if the server's `MaxConnections` is exceeded. Any other error on the listening thread(s) will trigger the `OnListenException` event. However, a lose of network connectivity does not guarantee an error on the listening socket, since listening is an operation on the local machine, not the network.  Short of the network adapter being listened on getting disabled, there is little chance of getting reported by a listening socket.

Comment: Clients connected to the server, on the other hand, will error and trigger the `OnDisconnect` event if the network connection is lost.

Comment: To do what you are asking, you will likely have to monitor the network adapter itself looking for notifications about its connectivity state. `TIdHTTPServer` will not give you that information.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Is there any chance of, because of an exception, the opened port become closed? I am having some strange issues that sometimes the server does not respond at all to requests. It seems to me that the server is no longer listening to the port it was before.

Comment: If an exception occurs on the listening socket, the socket is not closed, but who knows what the OS does internally with the physical port. It depends on the nature of the error. Have you tried using `netstat` to make sure the server's bound IP/Port is still in a **LISTENING** state?

Comment: @RemyLebeau No,I have not. Every time that the error occurs, our support team resets the server without give me chance to look for the problem. I understand them. There are 5000 customers using this server and they cant just sit and watch when something goes wrong. I am trying to log some stuff, or teach the support team to collect the data I need.

Comment: definately ask the support team to take note of netstat's output before rebooting.

Comment: I would highly recommend to set up a copy of this server in a test environment. This way, you won't need to worry about anyone else using this copy.

Comment: @JerryDodge Good idea. But I dont think i will be able to reproduce the problem without having 5,000 users using it. According to my tests, I need a lot of requests to simulate the problem. But thanks for you help.

Comment: True, I did think about that after commenting. Do you have a logging mechanism? Perhaps you could add a once-a-minute check if that port is open and record the listening status (Don't know how to do that programmatically though). You may also want to consider performing scheduled restarts to refresh everything anyway, for example, once a night at 12:00 am stop and restart the server socket.

Comment: @JerryDodge Great idea. I do not have logging mechanism but I am developing it now. Can you please make all your comments as an answer do I can accept it? (it helped me think better about the problem itself)

Comment: Regarding the test environment: there are many load test tools for HTTP which can simulate user requests and generate high traffic. I frequently use Apache JMeter for network and database load simulations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two  suggestions to help you solve your issue.

First of all, add a timer where once every minute (or interval of your choice), "ask" windows if your port is still listening or not. This must be done outside of Indy, as Indy has no mechanism to do this. If Windows tells you this port is not listening, then record this to a log and restart your server. Check this log periodically to see if your app has ever reported your port to stop listening. This will tell you if it really is disconnecting or not.

Second of all, you might want to consider a nightly restart of your server socket. For example, at midnight every night, stop and start the server socket to ensure a fresh connection. There might be some variable overflow, for example, if you are constantly incrementing a number and it keeps getting larger and larger, then over time, that number will become too large for your application to hold it. This can happen anywhere between 5 seconds or 5 months of run-time, depending on how fast you increment it.

Answer (score 3):

You could consider creating a watchdog connection to your server from its self connecting on an interval, when you were unable to connect you would then restart you server or whatever you need to do to correct the issue.

This does have the added bonus that you are actually testing the connection to you server so if any other issue happen that may cause client issues connection these will be picked up to.

This could also be done is a separate application which has the ability to close, kill and restart you server

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that, easy enough :D